# Check if client certificate is already installed in Android Programatically

Tags: android, kotlin, keystore, android-keystore

I have an android app where I am installing the client certificate using the following code.

```
 val inputStream: InputStream = resources.openRawResource(R.raw.client)
val intent = KeyChain.createInstallIntent()                           
val p12: ByteArray = inputStream.readBytes()                          
intent.putExtra(KeyChain.EXTRA_PKCS12, p12)                      
intent.putExtra(KeyChain.EXTRA_NAME, "Sample cert")                   
startActivityForResult(intent,3)
```

Now once user installs the certificate, I dont want to repeat this again so I want to check if the certificate is already installed.

I used the following code to check it, but doest get the certificate with both "AndroidCAStore" and "PKCS12".

"AndroidCAStore" - returns all trusted CA certs but my certificate is in user credentials.

"PKCS12" - IS empty

```
    //val ks = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidCAStore")                               
  val ks: KeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12")                               
  if (ks != null) {                                                               
      ks.load(null, null)                                                         
      val aliases = ks.aliases()                                                  
      while (aliases.hasMoreElements()) {                                         
          val alias = aliases.nextElement() as String                             
          val cert = ks.getCertificate(alias) as X509Certificate                  
          Log.d("Cert ---->",cert.issuerDN.name)                                  
          if (cert.issuerDN.name.contains(issuerDn)) {                            
              return true                                                         
          }                                                                       
      }                                                                           
  }
```

Can some one help me fix this.

Answer (score 0):

When you call

`val intent = KeyChain.createInstallIntent()`

you are storing the Certificate in the Android Keychain and I don't think there's a way of accessing the Certificates stored there programatecally, see [this unanswered post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71318696/check-if-client-certificate-is-already-installed-in-android-programatically).

Since you want to check if the certificate was installed in the `KeyChain`, you can call `KeyChain.getPrivateKey()` or `KeyChain.getCertificateChain()` and if they return null, then it means that the `Certificate` has not been installed yet.

**Note**: You have the limitation that you have to call `KeyChain.choosePrivateKeyAlias` first to establish trust between the app and the `KeyChain`, otherwise you'll get a `KeyChain` exception.

If you don't need to use the `KeyChain`, then you can simply create your own `KeyStore` and add your certificates to it. Then you will be able to call `aliases()` to get all of the aliases of the certificates in the `KeyStore`.